# How to create personalized(with passed/failed tests) Jenkins Build Monitor View?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have several tests jobs and I have a dashboard (Build Monitor View) for the same to display status. Which displays Job Name, Build Status, Possible culprits and last build time.

Now I have requirement where I would like to display the Number of Tests passed and Number of tests failed in last build (along with the URL of the result page,if possible) for each job. How Can I do that? Any help? (My test results are stored in workspace as XML format (NUnit Result Files).

Answer (score 1):

you can use dashboard plugin along with MashUp portlets plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mashup+Portlets

In MashUp Portlets, we have **Test Results Portlet**: Shows the test results for a configured job.

add your Test results to show it in Dashboard.